# Cannot call static content correctly

Tags: python, cherrypy

I am starting out with CherryPy v18.0.1 and am stuck on tutorial 6, found [here](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/tutorials.html#tutorial-6-what-about-my-javascripts-css-and-images).  I am also running Python v3.7.  I keep getting a 404 error when calling my style.css sheet from the tutorial and not sure where the issue lies.  I have seen that the '/static' dir needs to be set for security reasons, however things are not working as expected.  Here is what I have defined:

```
import os, os.path
import random
import string

import cherrypy


class StringGenerator(object):
@cherrypy.expose
def index(self):
    return """<html>
      <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
      <body>
        <form method="get" action="generate">
          <input type="text" value="8" name="length" />
          <button type="submit">Show me the number!</button>
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>"""

@cherrypy.expose
def generate(self, length=8):
    some_string = ''.join(random.sample(string.hexdigits, int(length)))
    cherrypy.session['mystring'] = some_string
    return some_string

@cherrypy.expose
def display(self):
    return cherrypy.session['mystring']


if __name__ == '__main__':
conf = {
    '/': {
        'tools.sessions.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.root': 'C:/python37'
    },
    '/static': {
        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.dir': 'static/Scripts/css'
    }
}
cherrypy.quickstart(StringGenerator(), '/', conf)
```

Based on my limited knowledge I am setting the root directory as "C:/python37", a file directory as "static/Scripts/css" and calling the stylesheet in:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Any clarification on this would be great. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From the tutorial you linked above:

- `tools.staticdir.root` is "root directory of all of our static content"
- `tools.staticdir.dir` is "all URLS [...] starts with /static will be served as static content [...] a direct child of the root directory."

This means the `root` directory should be a directory where all your content (HTML, CSS, images, fonts...) is located. Not the root of you python installation.

And the static `dir` is simply a subdirectory in the root directory. It can be named anything you want. CherryPy maps the `/static` path used as key in the configuration dictionary to the real name in your root directory.

Example:

```
conf = {
    '/': {
        'tools.sessions.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.root': 'C:/users/chad/tutorials/7'
    },
    '/static': {
        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.dir': 'public-content'
    }
}
```

Then, in this example, you should create `C:/users/chad/tutorials/7` as root directory for **all** static content with a subfolder named `public-content`, and inside it any folder where you put your styles and any other public content.

For a style sheet, you can have a `css` subfolder in (`C:/users/chad/tutorials/7/public-content/css`) and put your `style.css` inside. You'll link to it with:

```
<link href="/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
            ======= ###
```

The `static` path (marked with `=`) in the URL comes from the `/static` used as key in the config file.
The `css` path (marked with `#`) comes from the folder inside `C:/users/chad/tutorials/7/static-content`.

Note that the real name of the static folder, `public-content`, does not appear in the URLs.

Applying these rules you can have any directory structure you want. For instance, if you want images in `C:/users/chad/tutorials/7/public-content/images`, you'll link to them like this:

```
<img src="/static/images/logo.png">
           ====== ######
```